# Cassandra(2.0.4) is going down because of Too many open files

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.0

Currently, we are using cassandra version 2.0.14. machines are going down in cluster and i am seeing below exception in logs.

```
WARN [New I/O server boss #33] 2017-07-06 06:37:33,097 Slf4JLogger.java (line 76) Failed to accept a connection.
java.io.IOException: Too many open files
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:241)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss.process(NioServerBoss.java:100)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:312)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss.run(NioServerBoss.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
ERROR [COMMIT-LOG-ALLOCATOR] 2017-07-06 06:37:33,123 StorageService.java (line 377) Stopping RPC server
 INFO [COMMIT-LOG-ALLOCATOR] 2017-07-06 06:37:33,123 ThriftServer.java (line 141) Stop listening to thrift clients
ERROR [COMMIT-LOG-ALLOCATOR] 2017-07-06 06:37:33,132 StorageService.java (line 382) Stopping native transport
 INFO [COMMIT-LOG-ALLOCATOR] 2017-07-06 06:37:34,965 Server.java (line 182) Stop listening for CQL clients
ERROR [COMMIT-LOG-ALLOCATOR] 2017-07-06 06:37:34,969 CommitLog.java (line 390) Failed to allocate new commit log segments. Commit disk failure policy is stop; terminating thread
FSWriteError in /myntra/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-3-1499285518666.log
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegment.<init>(CommitLogSegment.java:143)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegment.freshSegment(CommitLogSegment.java:90)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogAllocator.createFreshSegment(CommitLogAllocator.java:262)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogAllocator.access$500(CommitLogAllocator.java:50)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogAllocator$1.runMayThrow(CommitLogAllocator.java:109)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /myntra/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-3-1499285518666.log (Too many open files)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:241)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegment.<init>(CommitLogSegment.java:125)
        ... 6 more
```

we had increased the resources limit as per datastax production recommendations. Cassandra is running by root user and file descriptor limit of root user is

```
[root@lgp-feed-cassandra2 cassandra]# ulimit -n
120000
```

And limits from the running process

```
[root@lgp-feed-cassandra2 cassandra]# cat /proc/117845/limits
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max stack size            10485760             unlimited            bytes
Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes
Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max processes             32768                32768                processes
Max open files            120000               120000               files
Max locked memory         unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks
Max pending signals       255823               255823               signals
Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes
Max nice priority         0                    0
Max realtime priority     0                    0
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us
```

not able to figure out exact reason of this problem. Any lead would be helpful.

Comment: Does this node only running Cassandra or something else also is running? Can you show the output of "iostat" and "top" command?

Comment: Cassandra will open sstables and commitlogs during startup - each sstable has 6 components. If you have 20k sstables on disk, you may hit that 120,000 limit (you may have 20k sstables on disk if compaction fell very far behind).

You can likely raise that limit from 120000 to 1000000 and see if the server will start, but you'll need to figure out how you got so many sstables on disk.

Comment: @JeffJirsa we found the issue. our python cassandra client opened lots of socket which caused the issue. we are still trying to find out to use connection pooling in python client.

Answer (score 1):

Need to set ulimit , first check ulimit by command  "ulimit -n". 
We have achieved by doing following changes :

root         hard    nofile    65535

root         soft    nofile    65535

hard    nofile    65535

soft    nofile    65535

$ sudo cat /etc/security/limits.conf

[Refer this link for more details](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/config/configRecommendedSettings.html#configRecommendedSettings__disable-swap)